# Contacts not receiving SMS again once sms is Received once - Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I have an issue in regards to contacts not being able to receive sms again once they received an sms before.

Orignally, I created a keyword attached to the "Stop". I changed it to be attached to the "Help". Basically Once they replied "UNSUB" it will update a data extension attribute and sales cloud record but not entirely unsubbing them to marketing cloud. This data extension attribute acts as a flag in the journey to know if we're going to send them sms again. They also have an opportunity to subscribe again using a cloud page that we created, This cloud page updates the data extension and also the sales cloud record.

The thing is even though they subscribed back. They can't seem to receive any sms eventhough I didn't attached the keyword to the "Account Stop".

I also checked the all contacts, and for the contact keys that are not receiving sms again. I checked their membership, their status is still opted in.

Am I missing something regarding "Default Code Settings" or i may need to do something else for customers to receive SMS again.

In my journey builder in the "Subscribe All Contact to a keyword" what does this mean? Does it mean like contacts will only receive sms again if they opted in the chose keyword?

Any insight will do. Regards

Comment: Check out this link, it can provide you with some usefull information: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284802/manage-transactional-promotional-mobileconnect-sends

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by attaching keywords to "Account Stop" and "Account Help"?

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak let me update the question. It's just actually help and stop keywords

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this issue by updating journey builder setting to allow contact re entry